# I need to figure out the max data ingestion rate for Firehose if I am reading it from a Kinesis data Stream?

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose

The doc state the below:
Kinesis Firehose can ingest only 5 MiB/sec and that the maximum size of a record sent to Kinesis Data Firehose, before base64-encoding, is 1,000 KiB.

Is there a way increase the ingestion rate for Kinesis Firehose ?
Does Firehose also use shards concepts ?
I am forwarding it to Kinesis Data Analytics after filtering data at Firehose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of dynamic partitioning, but that will help you with throughput(but not for ingestion rate).

If you are using dynamic partitioning, a max throughput of 40 MB per second is supported for each active partition. This is a hard limit.

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/limits.html), you can reach out to them to increase the quota.